# PHP DB2 odbc_exec() errors

Tags: php, db2, odbc

I'm writing a little web app for a price checker device but stuck at trying to retrieve the data using ODBC via a DB2 database in PHP.

I'm getting these errors (mainly concerned about the bolded/first warning):

> Warning: odbc_exec(): supplied resource is not a valid ODBC-Link
>   resource in C:\xampp\htdocs\db2\findme.php on line 43
>
> Warning: odbc_fetch_row() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean
>   given in C:\xampp\htdocs\db2\findme.php on line 46
>
> Warning: odbc_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string
>   given in C:\xampp\htdocs\db2\findme.php on line 53

And below is the code I have:

```
<html>
<head><title>Searching for item...</title>
</head>
<body bgcolor=#ffffff>

<?php
$username = "admin";
$password = "admin";
$hostname = "localhost";
$port = "50000";
$database="HLDB";

$conn_string = "DRIVER={IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER};DATABASE=$database;"."HOSTNAME=$hostname;PORT=$port;PROTOCOL=TCPIP;UID=$username;PWD=$password";

$conn = odbc_connect($conn_string, '', '');

echo "<h2>Search Results:</h2><p>";

//Retrieve input from find field on previous page and store in a variable
$find = $_POST['find'];

echo "User searched for: " . $find . "<br><br>";

//If they did not enter a search term we give them an error
if ($find == "")
{
echo "<p>Please scan for an item!";
exit;
}

// Otherwise we connect to our Database
if ($conn){
    echo "Connection succeeded. \n";
    odbc_close($conn);
}
else{
    echo "Connection failed. \n";
}

//Now we search for our search term, in the field the user specified
$sql = "SELECT * FROM NULLID.ITEMS WHERE 'ITEM NO.' LIKE '%$find%'";

$rs=odbc_exec($conn,$sql);

//fetch tha data from the database 
while(odbc_fetch_row($rs))
{
    //display the data
    echo odbc_result($rs, "Description 1"), "\n";
}

//This counts the number or results - and if there wasn't any it gives them a little message explaining that
$anymatches=odbc_num_rows($sql);
if ($anymatches == 0)
{
echo "Sorry, but we are unable to find this product...<br><br>";
}

//And we remind them what they searched for
echo "<b>Searched For:</b> " .$find;
?> 


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This has been awhile and sorry I didn't get back but I did your suggestion and everything is fine now. Thanks, how can I vote/thank you?

Comment: Replaced my comment by answer, so you can react if you would like.

Comment: I did thanks much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to keep the connection opened? Your code shows an odbc_close($conn); after you verify a successful connection. You should remove that line to keep the connection open otherwise $conn is not valid for the subsequent odbc_exec()